# ReactJS: Page update after login

Tags: reactjs

Im new to reactorJS, just trying to develop a simple login example.
In my example after button click page not updating with new component.
When I click submit button it should update the page regardless of user credentials.

```
    var UserAuthentication = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {signIn: false};
        },
        handleSubmit: function() {
            this.state.signIn = true;
        },
      render: function() {
        return (
         <div>
          {(this.state.signIn
             ? <User />     
             :<form>
              <div className="userNameIn">
                <label>Username :</label>
                   <input type="text" ref="userName"/>
                   </div>
                   <div className="userPasswordIn">
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="password" ref="userPassword"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <button type="submit" onClick= this.handleSubmit}>Sign in</button>
                    </div>
               </form>
                )}
                </div>
        );
      }
    });

var User = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="userName">
        <label>User in...</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a better practice is to put a handler not on a click action of the submit button, but on a form itself — by passing it a onSubmit prop. This way it will be triggered not just by button press, but also, for example, by pressing Enter on the form field.

```
<form onSubmit = { this.handleSubmit }>
 {...}
</form>
```

Secondly, simply setting the state object to the one you want won't do — React doesn't work this way and will simply ignore this statement. You have to use setState function, like this:

```
handleSubmit: function() {
   this.setState({ signIn: true });
}
```